# After getting values of html data-attributes how to pass the unique values to an iterable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this situation; I made an data-attribute to be able to keep the values that are a property of an object, like this 2 ones:

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">

    Servicios
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="AACC">
                    AACC Hab/Salón
                </td>

                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="APCO">
                    Aptos./Hab. con cocina
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="BAÑO">
                    Baño en habitación
                </td>

                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="MICR">
                    Microondas
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="NVRA">
                    Nevera
                </td>

                <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="PLYC">
                    Playa cercana
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

and another one:

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">

    Servicios
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="AACC">
                    AACC Hab/Salón
                </td>

                <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="ADAP">
                    Habitaciones minusvalidos
                </td>

                <tr>
                    <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                    <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="AERP">
                        Aeropuerto cercano
                    </td>

                    <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                    <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="APCO">
                        Aptos./Hab. con cocina
                    </td>

                    <tr>
                        <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                        <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="ASCR">
                            Ascensor
                        </td>

                        <!-- DATA-* LISTA SERVICIOS-->
                        <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" name="listaServicios" data-listservices="AUDI">
                            Alquiler audiovisuales
                        </td>

                        <tr>
                        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this x30 times. So at the end I have something like this:

In the chrome console I can get this:
[image]

But this is where I can reach now;
Code I have tried:

```js
var array = [];
    $(".listaServicios").each(function () {
        array.push($(this).attr("data-listservices"));
    });
    $("#test").append(array.join(","))
```

Above code return blank in ID "test".
Next more the same:

```js
    var dataServicios2 = $(".listaServicios").data("listservices");
    for (var i in dataServicios2) {
        console.log(i, dataServicios2[i])
    };
```

And so on not gonna post everything I tried otherwise you will start thinking bad about me :).
So my **question** is: How to get that values from `$('.listaServicios')` and take the non repeteated ones and them pass to and array to a list or whatever I can iterate it.
Thank you so much as usually!!!
If I am missing something just let me know!

Comment: None of the `.listaServicios` elements have a `data-title` attribute...? Do you mean `data-listservices` instead?

Comment: Note that I removed the C# and ASP.Net Core tags - they are not relevant.

Comment: Yes, why not?, I mean I can chose whatever name after data- isn´t it?, I mean; data-othername or data-whatService or I really need to make data-tittle?. I mean I named that data-attribute as a "data-listServices" what yes I want `data-listServices`.

Comment: You can make them anything you like, but the name you use in the JS needs to match what's in the HTML.

Comment: I read that are case sensitive thats I was writing like this... gonna try

Comment: I've added an answer for you below, which hopefully makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `data-title` in the JS, yet the HTML has `data-listservices`. They need to match.

There's a couple of other things to note here. Firstly you can simplify the JS by using jQuery's `map()` method to build the array. Secondly, it's better practice to use `data()` instead of `attr()` to retrieve data attributes. Finally, `td` elements do not have a `name` attribute. It needs to be removed to keep your HTML valid. Try this:

```js
var array = $(".listaServicios").map((i, e) => $(e).data('listservices')).get();
$("#test").append(array.join(","))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
  Servicios
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" data-listservices="AACC">AACC Hab/Salón</td>
        <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" data-listservices="APCO">Aptos./Hab. con cocina</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" data-listservices="BAÑO">Baño en habitación</td>
        <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" data-listservices="MICR">Microondas</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" data-listservices="NVRA">Nevera</td>
        <td class="col-md-6 listaServicios" data-listservices="PLYC">Playa cercana</td>
      </tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry Rory I wrote wrong but in the code it was okey, trying to make it works, I´ll let you know..

Comment: Yes it is perfect!, but it repeteas the values, sorry Rory this is my 2th in javascript jaja. Can I do something like distinct? Anyway I can handle this jaja. Thank you very much as usually!.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. There's lots of ways to dedupe an array, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/519413)